# Convert mysql query in laravel5.0

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I want to apply following query in my Laravel5.0 application

```
sql = "select c.User_ID, c.Name, c.Mobile_No from client as c where c.User_ID not in "
            + "(select b.User_ID from bill_history as b where "
            + "b.User_ID = c.User_ID )";
```

for the current month so that I can find the due users of month. What will be format of the above mentioned query in Laravel5.0?

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent(Assuming you have Client and BillHistory Model and App Namespace = App)

`$result = \App\Client::whereNotIn('User_ID', \App\BillHistory::lists('User_ID'))->select('User_ID', 'Name', 'Mobile_No')->get();`

Non Eloquent

`$result = \DB::table('client')->whereNotIn('User_ID', \DB::table('bill_history')->lists('User_ID'))->select('User_ID', 'Name', 'Mobile_No')->get();`